# How to remove the login prompt to Jupyter Hub when starting VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyterhub

For a while now, every time I start VS Code I get a prompt to put in my Jupyter Hub user name and password.

I've looked everywhere I can think of and haven't been able to get rid of it.

Any ideas?

[image: screenshot of login prompt]

Comment: it's coming from the Microsoft Jupyter extension

Comment: are you doing anything that requires logging in to a jupyter hub connection? related source code that ends up in code paths that do the prompt: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode-jupyter%20%22this.jupyterHubPasswordConnect.getPasswordConnectionInfo%22&type=code. potentially related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/14213 -> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13671.

Comment: I have connected to remote Jupyter servers in the past, but using a token, not a password. However my default kernel is local, so I don't understand why the prompt keeps coming back

Comment: this might be worth [raising an issue ticket about](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/new). If you do raise one, please ping me with a link to it.